# JavaScript animation, image animates only once

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have the following code :

HTML

```
<div class="gif">

</div>

<button class="stop">Stop</button>
```

CSS

```
.gif {
  background-image: url('https://img06.deviantart.net/4ba2/i/2012/053/c/c/stacey_run_sprite_sheet_by_django90-d4qo9pi.jpg');
  width: 140px;
  height: 220px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var $image = document.querySelector('.gif');
var $button = document.querySelector('.stop');

var id = setInterval(function () {
  $image.style.backgroundPosition = '-140px';
}, 60);

$button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  clearInterval(id);
});
```

Somehow the image animates only once. How can I keep it animated (loop the animation) ?

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dedrp7zj/)

Comment: May I ask why you chose an answer that doesn't take into account that your image size differs for each frame and as well needs to move vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your background position value.
the interval works fine but the background position is not changing!
its always set to -140px.

if you want it to decrease by 140 each time. you have to use variables.

try this:

```
var $position = 0;
var id = setInterval(function () {
    $position = $position - 140;
    $image.style.backgroundPosition = $position + 'px';
}, 60);
```

and this changes the position both vertically and horizontally.
I tries using it on fiddle it should be:

```
$image.style.backgroundPosition = $position + 'px 0';
```

this worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems here, where one is to increment moving horizontal and vertical (every 4:th step), and the other is that the images aren't easily divided as they differ in size.

One way would be to recreate the image, another is like this.

```js
var $image = document.querySelector('.gif');
var $button = document.querySelector('.start');
var $button2 = document.querySelector('.stop');

var $positionx = [0,-230,-515,-770,0,-230,-515,-770];
var $positiony = [0,0,0,0,-220,-220,-220,-220];
var $positioncounter = 0;
var id;


$button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (id) return;
    id = setInterval(function () {
    $positioncounter++;
    if ($positioncounter >= $positionx.length) {$positioncounter = 2}
    $image.style.backgroundPosition = $positionx[$positioncounter] + 'px ' + $positiony[$positioncounter] + 'px';
  }, 100);
});

$button2.addEventListener('click', function () {
  clearInterval(id);
  id = null;
  $positioncounter = 0;
  $image.style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
});
```

```css
.gif {
  background-image: url('https://img06.deviantart.net/4ba2/i/2012/053/c/c/stacey_run_sprite_sheet_by_django90-d4qo9pi.jpg');
  width: 180px;
  height: 220px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.stop {
  margin-left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gif"></div>
<button class="start">Start</button> <button class="stop">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you get the backgroundPosition values which return a String ,
not a number ,so  you have to do some manipulation to make the annimation work :

edit: Another probeleme is that your Images isn't correctly divided ( for sprite use ) : so I used another images that can work correctly :

**JS**

```
var $image = document.querySelector('.gif');
var $button = document.querySelector('.stop');
//get the img width
var imgWidth = window.getComputedStyle($image,null).width.replace("px", "");

var id = setInterval(function () {
  // get backround style axis (x y)
  style=window.getComputedStyle($image,null).backgroundPosition.trim().split(/\s+/);

  // replace px by nothing to get number string
  var position = style[0].replace("px", "");
    $image.style.backgroundPosition = parseInt(position)-parseInt(imgWidth)+"px 0px";
}, 100);

$button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    clearInterval(id);
});
```

try this : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dedrp7zj/7/) (Updated Fiddle)